# How to call predefined functions with different variable names?

Tags: python

How would I do something like this?

```
guy = for
guy i in range():
    (placeholder)
```

I am pretty sure this is possible but don't know how to go about wording the question to find out the answer.

Comment: You can't do this. You can't use variables for the language syntax elements.

Comment: No, it's not possible  `for` is not a function, it is a statement.  Very different.

Comment: You may want to learn `lisp`.  Horrible practices like that are easy in `lisp`.

Comment: Please explain your use case for wanting to do this.  What other values would you want for `guy`, and how is this useful to you?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make an alias for a syntactic keyword; those words are hard-coded into the language definition.  I suspect that you have an "X-Y problem" -- using the wrong specific technique on a more general problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since `for` is not a **function** but is rather a **keyword**, (functions have a little parenthesis at the end, such as `foo()`). This is not possible with keywords, but is possible with functions.